# Parsing through rows and isolating student records from Spark Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

My student database has multiple records for each student in the table Student.

I am reading the data into a Spark dataframe and then iterate through a Spark Dataframe, isolate records for each student and do some processing for each student records.

My code so far:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("app") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2") \
    .getOrCreate()

class_3A = spark_session.sql("SQL") 

for row in class_3A:
    #for each student
        #Print Name, Age and Subject Marks
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It would be helpful if you could provide some more context to what you're trying to accomplish. "Isolate" and "process" is quite vague.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I think I wanted to have the flexibility of the Pandas data frame so I converted the Spark data frame to a Pandas data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use SparkSQL

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('Suresh',20),('Bala',26)],['name','age'])
>>> df.show()
+--------+---+                                                                  
|    name|age|
+--------+---+
|   Ankit| 25|
|Jalfaizy| 22|
|  Suresh| 20|
|    Bala| 26|
+--------+---+

>>> df.where('age > 20').show()
+--------+---+
|    name|age|
+--------+---+
|   Ankit| 25|
|Jalfaizy| 22|
|    Bala| 26|
+--------+---+

>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.select('name', col('age') + 100).show()
+--------+-----------+
|    name|(age + 100)|
+--------+-----------+
|   Ankit|        125|
|Jalfaizy|        122|
|  Suresh|        120|
|    Bala|        126|
+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Imperative approach(in addition to Bala's SQL approach):

```py
class_3A = spark_session.sql("SQL") 

def process_student(student_row):
    # Do Something with student_row
    return processed_student_row

#"isolate records for each student"
# Each student record will be passed to process_student function for processing.
# Results will be accumulated to a new DF - result_df
result_df = class_3A.map(process_student)

# If you don't care about results and just want to do some processing:
class_3A.foreach(process_student)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each records in a dataframe and access them with the column names

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('Suresh',20),('Bala',26)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1])))
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(people)

schemaPeople.show(10, False)

for row in schemaPeople.rdd.collect():
  print("Hi " + str(row.name) + " your age is : " + str(row.age) )
```

This will produce an output as below

```
+---+--------+
|age|name    |
+---+--------+
|25 |Ankit   |
|22 |Jalfaizy|
|20 |Suresh  |
|26 |Bala    |
+---+--------+

Hi Ankit your age is : 25
Hi Jalfaizy your age is : 22
Hi Suresh your age is : 20
Hi Bala your age is : 26
```

So you can do your processing or some logic that you need to perform on each record of your dataframe.

Comment: Not the most efficient way to use Spark. You upload data to a dataframe only to collect it and process with python loop? This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand the question right but if you want to do operation on 
rows based on any column you can do that using dataframe functions .  Example :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from  pyspark.sql import Window



sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").\
config("spark.driver.memory","1g").\
config("spark.executor.cores",2).\
config("spark.max.cores",4).getOrCreate()

df1 = sc.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("test.csv")

w = Window.partitionBy("student_id")

df2 = df1.groupBy("student_id").agg(f.sum(df1["marks"]).alias("total"))
df3 = df1.withColumn("max_marks_inanysub",f.max(df1["marks"]).over(w))
df3 = df3.filter(df3["marks"] == df3["max_marks_inanysub"])


df1.show()
df3.show()
```

sample data

student_id,subject,marks
1,maths,3
1,science,6
2,maths,4
2,science,7

output

+----------+-------+-----+
|student_id|subject|marks|
+----------+-------+-----+
|         1|  maths|    3|
|         1|science|    6|
|         2|  maths|    4|
|         2|science|    7|
+----------+-------+-----+

+----------+-------+-----+------------------+
|student_id|subject|marks|max_marks_inanysub|
+----------+-------+-----+------------------+
|         1|science|    6|                 6|
|         2|science|    7|                 7|
+----------+-------+-----+------------------+